# Filter menu drop down in Kendo UI For Angular grid

Tags: angular, user-interface, filter, kendo-ui, grid

After making a Kendo UI Angular Grid Filterable, A small square button appears next to the filter Input box. A drop-down appears when clicking on this button with options like 'is equal to', 'is not equal to', 'contains' etc. (pls see attached picture). My question is how to change this list by firstly displaying only the options I want, secondly how to change the text because I need it in German.
Thanks

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Grid Messages to provide the desired text for the filter operators (or the application translation mechanics, outlined in the documentation):

[DOCS ON MESSAGES](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/globalization/#toc-messages)

[LIST OF MESSAGES AVAILABLE FOR CUSTOMIZATION](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CustomMessagesComponent/)

To specify which operators will be displayed, use the approach, demonstrated in the following section:

[CHANGE THE ORDER AND NUMBER OF OPERATORS](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/built-in-template/#toc-setting-the-order-of-the-filter-operators)

Comment: Thanks - very helpful.